# Exception caught by widgets library ,The following assertion was thrown building Answer **error** in flutter

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, flutter, dart

[image]

I'm new to flutter , or programming to be clear . I was following a course , doing the same as the Instructor , the app worked for him , but when i try to run it ,this error shows up .

```
// @dart=2.9

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';



class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz(
      {@required this.questions,
      @required this.answerQuestion,
      @required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'],
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means that your map has a null value somewhere. Change your code to this:

```
Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']??"NA"), answer['text']??"NA");
```

Comment: Maybe you'll need to do it also for "questions". Basically look into your widgets, where you have a Text widget, and make sure you account for null values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is propably that the person from the course uses an older version of Flutter which doesn't use [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety). So to solve this you need to migrate your code to null safety. For more information on how and when to use null safety you can refer to this great [video from Robert Brunehage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSC4o3cKo0Y). The Fixes you need to do on your code are the following:

**1.** change `@required` to `required`

**2.** add a question Mark to variables that don't have a value,

***Bad example:***

```
int questionIndex;
```

This will lead to a null error because `name` doesnt have a value (means it is null)

***Correct example***

```
int? questionIndex;
```

This variable is now null safe which prevents it from ending up with an error.

**3.** after you've now made your variables without a default value null safe you have to add `!` at some places (your IDE should show you where to add it normally)

***Wrong code:***

```
questions[questionIndex]['questionText'],
```

***Correct code***

```
questions[questionIndex!]['questionText'],
```

**If you don't want to use Null safety (not recommended!)**

you can give your Widget a default Text in case your variable has no value (is null)

```
Question(questions[questionIndex]['questionText']?? "default value",),
```